# AWS access keys and federation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, federated-identity

If an application runs in a corporate Data center (i.e. outside of AWS environment) and uses corporate credentials from its on premise Microsoft Active Directory as the sign in mechanism, would that application be able to federate into AWS programatically (i.e. use AWS federation, programatically) and access AWS resources via a role? I am trying to find out if this can be considered as an approach to avoid using access keys (access key ID and secret access key) within an application running outside of AWS environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for AWS Identity Pools, where you can integrate with custom identity providers and then exchange them for AWS credentials. Have a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-identity-pools.html

Comment: Thank you osh ! - that leads me to another question - What are the scenarios you are left with no choice but use only access keys (access key ID and secret access key) to access AWS resources? Is it when there is no Active Directory or identity provider available?